# python queue.Queue put() with negative timeout does not raise ValueError

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code below:

```
from queue import Queue
ku = Queue()
ku.put(1)
ku.put(2, timeout=-10) # This should raise negative timeout exception?
```

***Expected***:  Since a negative timeout is passed `ValueError` should have been raised.
Looking at [source here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py#L133) , it seems when Queue is initialized with a `maxsize` parameter , only then [a check for negative timeout](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/queue.py#L137) is done.

Did I miss something which is documented somewhere? 
Is there any reason for doing a negative check only when `maxsize` is supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, maxsize is here 0 so the timeout is not even checked.

The semantics of put() is that the operation is blocking until a slot is available. Since you don't specify a maxsize, there is no reason to block because you allow any size of queue.

The doc for reference : https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put

Comment: yes, as i have mentioned this in my question, whats the point of checking timeout only when there is a `maxsize`